# Trying to make andyvr/picEdit plugin upload file via JQUERY post/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I'm using a lightweight image editor jQuery plugin called andyvr/picEdit
https://github.com/andyvr/picEdit

This is just a plugin that turns an input:file element into an HTML canvass, and allows the user to select/edit/crop/manipulate an image file on the client side. The actual uploading and processing is done via the usual FORM UPLOAD and PHP $_FILE processes.

What I wanted to do is grab the "edited" picture data from this plugin and send it via $.post() instead of through the Form submit action.

Do you guys know what element I should select to include in my post variables?

```
var postvars = {};
postvars.final_image = $("#what_element").val();

$.post("script-name.php", postvars ,function(data){.....
```

I tried to go through the JS file but I can't seem to figure it out.

PS
I hope I came across clear with this question. I was having a hard time structuring it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the same picedit as I used and are still looking for an answer:

### The html file input:

```
<input type='file' name='thefile' id='thebox'>
```

### The jquery to make the file input act like an image edit box:

```
$(function() {
    $('#thebox').picEdit();
});
```

### The post command:

```
$.post( "handler.php", { story_edited : 1, id : 1 }, function( data ){ document.getElementById( 'photos' ).innerHTML = html =  data }, "html" );
```

### Notes:

handler.php = the name of the file that you want to use to process the input!

```
<div id='photos' name='photos'>
```

is a standard div tag that I use to update onscreen info in another part of the page! So, document.getElementById( 'photos' ).innerHTML will load handlers.php in to the photos div tag!

### Use:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
```

to process the images as normal file upload from a web page!

I have one other button that pulls it all together. After I finish editing the image, I click on an update button that calls the handler and uploads and saves the file as well as dynamic updating of a photoalbum section elsewhere on the page.

### TODO:

If I could find a way to attach a callback function I would not need to use this separate button.

Comment: Hey, I am looking for solution to upload file. I am pretty happy with client-side interaction. Can you guide?

Comment: @Pramod I can help, but will need more info on what you have and what your trying to do!

Comment: Thank you for kind reply. I am using same plugin. But not able to send image to server. I couldnt understand how to use it, I suppose. Is there any other way, i can reach you to describe in detail?

Comment: html code to display the file upload onscreen. Where id is 'thebox'.
<input type='file' name='thefile' id='thebox'>

jquery to create image edit box. Notice how '#thebox' uses the html id

$(function() {
    $('#thebox').picEdit();
});

This is called after user clicked the Open button on the file select window.

"handler.php" is the php file called, it will upload the files

$.post( "handler.php", { story_edited : 1, id : 1 }, function( data ){ document.getElementById( 'photos' ).innerHTML = html =  data }, "html" );

foreach uploads selected files

foreach($_FILES as $file){
 ...
}

Comment: I used
Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php 

To process the files!

include_once "SimpleImage.php"; 


foreach($_FILES as $file) {

 $image = new SimpleImage();
 $image->load( $file[ "tmp_name" ] );
 $image->save( $filename );

}

You can of course resize and or manipulate the images while processing them!

Comment: Thank you @user3633383, I am using a form to send captured or cropped image to server using post method (with multipart) but happens to be that file is not being sent on server side. I will reply with my code ASAP. Travelling now. I think my issue is either with handler.php or not setting something right to send file to server in HTML form :)